# WMPlayer embed not playing video

Tags: html, video-streaming, mp4, wmp, embedded-video

In my company we link our site to videos provided by a partner company. They changed their video encoding from .FLV to .MP4 videos and the current video player on our site doesn't playe them. We changed it to Windows Media Player given that most of our customers are running windows and internet explorer, the embed code we used is this one:

```
<object>
  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
    name="VideoPlayer" ShowStatusBar="false" 
    EnableContextMenu="false" autostart="true" 
    width="426" height="285" loop="false" 
    src=[video_url] />
</object>
```

I see the WMPlayer displayed on the site and the video plays, but my clients only see the player displayed and the video doesn't play. We updated our clients flash plugin and still nothing. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using [Flow Player](http://flowplayer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install additional codecs on the client machine. There are numerous codec packs for that (search google). You can't do it automatically from a browser either as it requires an installer to run.

WMP is a pretty crappy solution anyways since you're basically screwing over anyone who visits your site with a Mac or Linux computer. There are numerous other ways to play MP4 including via Flash but also using new HTML5 features.

Comment: We chose WMP because the majority of our traffic is Windows and IE, specifically IE6 and IE7. We did this as a quick fix until we could find a proper flash player. Also, HTML5 is not an option because most of the clients use older browsers.

Comment: html5 video tag has fallbacks, so you serve html5 video then WMP or whatever by nesting the tags. My point is only that "majority" is not 100% so you'll still get tech calls from Mac clients if you don't do it properly in the first place.